# Android soft menu overlapped when using a progressive web app

Tags: android, reactjs, progressive-web-apps

I'm developing a progressive web app, and after running it on my phone using a in `manifest.json` `"display": "fullscreen"`.
I found out that, whenever I'm using the virtual keyboard, it will not bring up the usual 'soft menu' that is just below it (I'm using a Pixel 2 XL).
Here are some screenshots so you can understand what I mean :
[image]

There is no soft menu whenever the keyboard comes up when I want to type something, so If I want to hide the keyboard by taping on the bottom left, it can trigger a button on my pwa UI.

However, if I try to "slide up" with my finger from the bottom of the screen, it will show up the soft menu as shown here :

[image]

This interaction seems a little off, and it doesn't offer a good user experience, for now I'm mostly using the browser base version since trying to hide the keyboard will often result in triggering a link or a button on the web app.

Do you have any ideas how to correct this?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Have you checked the logs to see where the error is coming from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using [display mode](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/web-app-manifest/#display) `fullscreen`. Fullscreen mode:

> Opens the web application without any browser UI and takes up the entirety of the available display area.

This includes the status bar at the top (with clock, etc) and the navigation bar at the bottom.

If you want the navigation bar to be visible to the user without them having to swipe it visible, you'll have to use the `standalone` display mode.